# Cakephp query for counting row as per user's InTime and OutTime

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

Cake query for counting row as per user's "In time" and "Out Time".

I have "In time" and "Out Time" of users in user table and want to find out total number of users of specific interval, if user's exit or out in that interval then minus the total number of users and if in then plus the total number of users.

Here I want count How many users(out minus(-) In) in every 5minutes interval. 
Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query like

```
$this->Users->find('all',[
'conditions' =>[
  'Users.in_time >' =>$intime,
  'Users.out_time <' =>$outtime,
  ]
])->count();
```

or you can use **mysql between** in cakephp details [Check here](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#advanced-conditions)